# Haskell ReadP parse at least one of the list

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, parser-combinators

I try to parse a command (create) with the ReadP standard lib. My command should start by the string `create`, then contains at least one word/tag/due, and potentially an option. Here my actual expression:

```hs
createExpr :: ReadP [Arg]
createExpr = do
  skipSpaces
  cmd <- SetCmd <$> cmdAliasExpr ["create", "add"]
  skipSpaces
  rest <-
    many1
    $   (AddWord <$> wordExpr)
    <|> (AddTag <$> addTagExpr)
    <|> (SetDue <$> dueExpr)
    <|> (AddOpt <$> optExpr)
  skipSpaces
  return $ cmd : rest
```

The problem is, if I call `create` with just one option, it parses well. But it shouldn't, since I expect at least one word/tag/due. How can I express this?

---

#### **[EDIT] I found the solution, thanks to [@M. Aroosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8491228/m-aroosi).**

In fact, I used the wrong operator. `<++`, *the local, exclusive, left-biased choice*, fits better my needs. Once an expression is matched, it should not check for the other ones:

```
notAnOpt arg = case arg of
  AddOpt _ -> False
  _        -> True


createExpr :: ReadP [Arg]
createExpr = do
  skipSpaces
  cmd <- SetCmd <$> cmdAliasExpr ["create", "add"]
  skipSpaces
  rest <-
    many1
    $   (AddTag <$> addTagExpr)
    <++ (SetDue <$> dueExpr)
    <++ (AddOpt <$> optExpr)
    <++ (AddWord <$> wordExpr)
  skipSpaces
  guard $ isJust $ find notAnOpt rest
  return $ cmd : rest
```

Comment: you could check if `rest` has at least 1 word/tag/due (`filter` and then `null` check, for example) and use `guard` from `Control.Monad` to make sure the parser fails in such cases.

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand what you say. Could you provide me an example?

Comment: Don't add the answer to the question...

Comment: Did you read ALL the comments? I found the solution thanks to the help I received. I asked the owner (M. Aroosi) to update his answer with what I've found, then I will validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use `guard` from `Control.Monad`.
Assuming a function like `isOpt :: Arg -> Bool` which is along the lines of

```
isOpt :: Arg -> Bool
isOpt (AddOpt _) = True
isOpt _          = False
```

then your definition of `createExpr` changes to

```
createExpr :: ReadP [Arg]
createExpr = do
    skipSpaces
    cmd <- SetCmd <$> cmdAliasExpr ["create", "add"]
    skipSpaces
    rest <-
      many1
      $   (AddWord <$> wordExpr)
      <|> (AddTag <$> addTagExpr)
      <|> (SetDue <$> dueExpr)
      <|> (AddOpt <$> optExpr)
    guard $ at_least_one_non_optional rest
    skipSpaces
    return $ cmd : rest
  where at_least_one_non_optional = not . null . filter (not . isOpt)
```

`guard` basically fails the parser when its argument is `False`, and more generally it works with any `Alternative` by returning `empty` when the argument is `False`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I achieved the same with `isJust $ find atLeastOne rest`. But it leads to another problem. If I type `create --opt`, I have `[([SetCmd "create",AddWord "--json"],"")]`. I guess it's because `optExpr` fails, it falls back to `wordExpr`.

Comment: @soywod this sounds like your `wordExpr` and `optExpr` both accept `"--json"`, in which case the parser `(AddWord <$> wordExpr) <|> (AddTag <$> addTagExpr) <|> (SetDue <$> dueExpr) <|> (AddOpt <$> optExpr)` tries both `wordExpr` and `optExpr` both of which succeed.

Comment: What do you mean by tries both? It will try one only if the first fail, isn't it? Indeed, `wordExpr` is like "the trash". Everything that does not match opt/tag/due will end up as a word.

Comment: `(<|>)` is defined as `(+++)` for `ReadP` which is commutative, it tries all the options and returns all the results. for example try to see the result of parsing "hello" with the parser `(0 <$ string "hello") <|> (1 <$ string "hello")`. you can use `(<++)` for a left-biased choice, that is if the left parser succeeds it won't try the right one.

Comment: Yes indeed, `(<++)` seems to better fit my needs. I will play a bit with and come back to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to do what I was looking for :) I would like to validate your answer: could you please update it with the solution I found (I edited my post with)?